# Creating Modifiable Text

Tags: xstring

I was wondering if there was a way to create a string variable?

I need to use a WHILE loop where I remove the first char of a string, and I need to have that saved.

I tried other ways:

- to put the length of the string in the loop, so I can reach the last char, not possible
- to use a counter to determine which char to examine, but it is not possible since it seems you can't put counters in parameters

Comment: your question is not at all clear, after `\def\zz{abcdef}` then `\edef\zz{\expandafter\@gobble\zz}`  then `\zz` has lost its first character and is `bcdef` is that what you are looking for?, obviously you could loop repeating that until it is empty.

Comment: "it seems ..."  don't post your speculation, post a minimal working example with your code + what you think the code does + what it actually do instead. // Have you tried using expl3 or LuaTeX to do the programming?

Comment: While the package suffers many problems, not least of which is its inefficient slowness, the `stringstrings` package (https://ctan.org/pkg/stringstrings) has many macros for examining and dissecting strings.